# metadata-gen fails with exit code None

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

I am going through the flipper tutorial and am getting an error when running metadata-gen.

```
ERROR: `"/Users/home/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "run" "--package" "metadata-gen" "--manifest-path=/var/folders/xj/m862kvrj73x04dvsfr6vs_fm0000gn/T/cargo-contract_c9GVwB/Cargo.toml" "--target-dir=/Users/home/src/testcontract/target" "--release"` failed with exit code: None
```

Having an exit code of None is really not helpful. Does anyone know the reason for this? Build and test works fine. I did a cargo update yesterday.

I'm on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to the 10-6 nightly tools the error went away.